# חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ and חַי יְהוָה in 1 Samuel 25:26

Tags: hebrew, 1-samuel

In 1 Sam. 25:26, there are two English phrases

> <sup>26</sup> “Now therefore, my lord, as **the LORD lives** and as **your soul lives**, since the LORD has held you back from coming to bloodshed and from avenging yourself with your own hand, now then, let your enemies and those who seek harm for my lord be as Nabal. <sup>NKJV, ©1982</sup>

The Hebrew text translates “the LORD lives” from חַי יְהוָה (*chai Yahveh*) while “your soul lives” is translated from חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ (*chei nafshekha*). The difference is the vowel point (*nikkud*) under the letter ח.

But, why the difference? Why does the Hebrew text have **חַי** יְהוָה instead of **חֵי** יְהוָה for “the LORD lives”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "Samuelism" in our verse and also in<sup>1</sup>:

1. **I Samuel 1:26** וַתֹּאמֶר בִּי אֲדֹנִי **חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ** אֲדֹנִי אֲנִי הָאִשָּׁה הַנִּצֶּבֶת עִמְּכָה בָּזֶה לְהִתְפַּלֵּל אֶל יְהוָה
2. **I Samuel 17:55** וְכִרְאוֹת שָׁאוּל אֶת דָּוִד יֹצֵא לִקְרַאת הַפְּלִשְׁתִּי אָמַר אֶל אַבְנֵר שַׂר הַצָּבָא בֶּן מִי זֶה הַנַּעַר אַבְנֵר וַיֹּאמֶר אַבְנֵר **חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ** הַמֶּלֶךְ אִם יָדָעְתִּי
3. **I Samuel 20:3** וַיִּשָּׁבַע עוֹד דָּוִד וַיֹּאמֶר יָדֹעַ יָדַע אָבִיךָ כִּי מָצָאתִי חֵן בְּעֵינֶיךָ וַיֹּאמֶר אַל יֵדַע זֹאת יְהוֹנָתָן פֶּן יֵעָצֵב וְאוּלָם **חַי יְהוָה וְחֵי נַפְשֶׁךָ** כִּי כְפֶשַׂע בֵּינִי וּבֵין הַמָּוֶת
4. **II Samuel 11:11** וַיֹּאמֶר אוּרִיָּה אֶל דָּוִד הָאָרוֹן וְיִשְׂרָאֵל וִיהוּדָה יֹשְׁבִים בַּסֻּכּוֹת וַאדֹנִי יוֹאָב וְעַבְדֵי אֲדֹנִי עַל פְּנֵי הַשָּׂדֶה חֹנִים וַאֲנִי אָבוֹא אֶל בֵּיתִי לֶאֱכֹל וְלִשְׁתּוֹת וְלִשְׁכַּב עִם אִשְׁתִּי חַיֶּךָ **וְחֵי נַפְשֶׁךָ אִם** אֶעֱשֶׂה אֶת הַדָּבָר הַזֶּה
5. **II Samuel 14:19** וַיֹּאמֶר הַמֶּלֶךְ הֲיַד יוֹאָב אִתָּךְ בְּכָל זֹאת וַתַּעַן הָאִשָּׁה וַתֹּאמֶר **חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ** אֲדֹנִי הַמֶּלֶךְ אִם אִשׁ לְהֵמִין וּלְהַשְׂמִיל מִכֹּל אֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר אֲדֹנִי הַמֶּלֶךְ כִּי עַבְדְּךָ יוֹאָב הוּא צִוָּנִי וְהוּא שָׂם בְּפִי שִׁפְחָתְךָ אֵת כָּל הַדְּבָרִים הָאֵלֶּה
6. **II Kings 2:2** וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלִיָּהוּ אֶל אֱלִישָׁע שֵׁב נָא פֹה כִּי יְהוָה שְׁלָחַנִי עַד בֵּית אֵל וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלִישָׁע **חַי יְהוָה וְחֵי נַפְשְׁךָ** אִם אֶעֶזְבֶךָּ וַיֵּרְדוּ בֵּית אֵל
7. **II Kings 4:30** וַתֹּאמֶר אֵם הַנַּעַר **חַי יְהוָה וְחֵי נַפְשְׁךָ** אִם אֶעֶזְבֶךָּ וַיָּקָם וַיֵּלֶךְ אַחֲרֶיהָ

The difference in meaning is:

1. חַי יְהוָה - "[As] the LORD lives", חי is a verb in *kal* form. This phrase is a form of an oath using the name of the LORD
2. חֵי נַפְשְׁךָ - "[by] the life of your soul", חי is a noun in construct form. This phrase is a form of an oath using the second person singular

When used together, these forms express an ultimative expression of conviction or confession.

---

1. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%9A